# SharePoint 2010 AspMenu - Use OnClick instead of OnMouseOver?

Tags: 2010, navigation, custom-masterpage

Is it possible to have the SharePoint AspMenu control to show its flyouts (sub items) based on the user clicking the item, rather than based on the mouseover (or hover)?